# How to set up an article input function based on forms in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

New to Django.

I am trying to build a **blog** of my own, so I will need to input an article with `max_length = 5000` or some other number; I don't want to use the admin system directly, instead I want to input the article and submit it to the server.Right now I am trying to use **forms**.

The question is I didn't find a solution to this huge amount of character inputs.

Any hint to this?

The form:

```
<form name="input" method="POST">
  <li>The title:{{ form.name }}</li> 
  <li>The body: <textarea cols='20' rows='20'>{{ form.text }}</textarea> </li> 
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

---

UPDATE:
    I solved this issue by deleting the textarea tag wrapping {{ form.text }};
{{ form.text }} itself implements a textarea tag.
And in my view code:

```
text = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Comment: What do you mean that **you cann't find a solution for that huge amount of character inputs**?

Comment: The form :
        <form name="input" method="POST">
  <li>The title:{{ form.name }}</li>
  <li>The body:
   <textarea cols='20' rows='20'>{{ form.text }}</textarea>
  </li>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
I am trying to deal with form.text

Comment: There is no need to wrap `{{ form.text }}` in textarea tags, simply using `{{ form.as_table }}` or `<form>{{form.text}}</form>` instead.

Comment: Thank you! This did work out.